# open source fingerprint sensor driver for dell xps 13 9310?

Tags: drivers, xps, fingerprint-reader, unlock

The `lsusb` on my Dell XPS 13 9310 shows this:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
```

if I rememebr correctly, there's a priprietary driver for this sensor.

Is there a open source alternative?